# Python/Pandas - TypeError when concatenating MultiIndex DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multi-index

I have trouble concatenating a list of MultiIndex DataFrames with 2 levels, and adding a third one to distinguish them.

As an example, I have following input data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Input data

start = '2020-01-01 00:00+00:00'
end = '2020-01-01 02:00+00:00'
pr1h = pd.period_range(start=start, end=end, freq='1h')

midx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Sup',1),('Sup',2),('Inf',1),('Inf',2)], names=['Data','Position'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4), index=pr1h, columns=midx1)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4), index=pr1h, columns=midx1)

midx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Sup',3),('Inf',3)], names=['Data','Position'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2), index=pr1h, columns=midx2)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2), index=pr1h, columns=midx2)
```

So df1 & df2 have data for the same tag `1h` and while they have the same column names at `Data` level, they don't have the same column names at `Position` level.

```
df1
Data                   Sup                 Inf          
Position                 1         2         1         2
2020-01-01 00:00  0.660795  0.538452  0.861801  0.502479
2020-01-01 01:00  0.205806  0.847124  0.474861  0.906546
2020-01-01 02:00  0.681480  0.479512  0.631771  0.961844

df2
Data                   Sup       Inf
Position                 3         3
2020-01-01 00:00  0.758533  0.672899
2020-01-01 01:00  0.096463  0.304843
2020-01-01 02:00  0.080504  0.990310
```

Now, df3 and df4 follow the same logic and same column names. To distinguish them from df1 & df2, I want to use a different tag, `2h` for instance.

I want to add this third level named `Period` during the call to `pd.concat`. For this, I am trying to use `keys` parameter in `pd.concat()`. I tried following code.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
period_list = ['1h', '1h', '2h', '2h']
concatenated = pd.concat(df_list, keys=period_list, names=('Period', 'Data', 'Position'), axis=1)
```

But this raises following error.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'slice'
```

Please, any idea what is the correct call for this?

I thank you for your help. Bests,

**EDIT 05/05**

As requested, here is desired result (copied directly from the answer given. Result obtained from given answer is the one I am looking for).

```
Period                  1h                                                    \
Data                   Sup                 Inf                 Sup       Inf   
Position                 1         2         1         2         3         3   
2020-01-01 00:00  0.309778  0.597582  0.872392  0.983021  0.659965  0.214953   
2020-01-01 01:00  0.467403  0.875744  0.296069  0.131291  0.203047  0.382865   
2020-01-01 02:00  0.842818  0.659036  0.595440  0.436354  0.224873  0.114649   

Period                  2h                                                    
Data                   Sup                 Inf                 Sup       Inf  
Position                 1         2         1         2         3         3  
2020-01-01 00:00  0.356250  0.587131  0.149471  0.171239  0.583017  0.232641  
2020-01-01 01:00  0.397165  0.637952  0.372520  0.002407  0.556518  0.523811  
2020-01-01 02:00  0.548816  0.126972  0.079793  0.235039  0.350958  0.705332
```

Comment: The problem is not really that you have multiindex at first, is more then you have twice the same value in the `period_list`. If you didn't have multiindex at first, then the error would be more explicit to the problem: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: Setting `period_list = ['1h', '2h', '3h', '4h']` works. Otherwise , please post desired result.

Comment: @Parfait  Hi, I added the expected result as requested. `df1` and `df2` have to share the same `Period`, and `df3` and `df4` have to share also a same `Period`.

Comment: it is actually similar to this [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33114) on github

Comment: Thanks, i have subscribed to this issue. If it is solved, I will modify the code you propose. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix would be to use different names in `period_list` and `rename` just after the `concat`. Something like:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
period_list = ['1h_a', '1h_b', '2h_a', '2h_b']
concatenated = pd.concat(df_list, 
                         keys=period_list, 
                         names=('Period', 'Data', 'Position'), 
                         axis=1)\
                 .rename(columns={col:col.split('_')[0] for col  in period_list}, 
                         level='Period')

print (concatenated)
Period                  1h                                                    \
Data                   Sup                 Inf                 Sup       Inf   
Position                 1         2         1         2         3         3   
2020-01-01 00:00  0.309778  0.597582  0.872392  0.983021  0.659965  0.214953   
2020-01-01 01:00  0.467403  0.875744  0.296069  0.131291  0.203047  0.382865   
2020-01-01 02:00  0.842818  0.659036  0.595440  0.436354  0.224873  0.114649   

Period                  2h                                                    
Data                   Sup                 Inf                 Sup       Inf  
Position                 1         2         1         2         3         3  
2020-01-01 00:00  0.356250  0.587131  0.149471  0.171239  0.583017  0.232641  
2020-01-01 01:00  0.397165  0.637952  0.372520  0.002407  0.556518  0.523811  
2020-01-01 02:00  0.548816  0.126972  0.079793  0.235039  0.350958  0.705332
```

Edit: as speed is a concern, it seems that rename is slow, so you can do:

```
concatenated = pd.concat(df_list, 
                         keys=period_list,
                         axis=1)
concatenated.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col[0].split('_')[0], col[1], col[2]) 
                                                  for col in concatenated.columns], 
                                                  names=('Period', 'Data', 'Position'), )
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T. I am surprised, is there no "direct" way to have the right tags? Your fix is nice, but still add some complexity. Thanks a lot for what you bring.

Comment: @pierre_j I'm not sure why it is not possible and the idea of Parfait is another way around, but because it is not possible even with non-multiindex makes me think that there will be no direct way

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you seem to be rather expert in pandas, I would like to mention that I have compared both methods in terms of speed and method of @Parfait appears to be 30% faster. I could read in several places that cumulated use of `pd.concat` leads to performance issues. I was certainly not expecting this result compared to a "simple" `rename()`. Please, do you have any idea what may be the cause of such a result (`pd.concat` being faster than `rename()`)?

Comment: @pierre_j I now that `rename` is not especially fast, but slower than 2 inner `concat`, is a bit surprising. I just tested and I have similar performance over a 4 year 1h interval period. If speed is a concern, see my edit, you can call MultiIndex.from_tuples, it is way faster on my side

Comment: thanks a lot for your constant support! You are of great help!

Answer (score 2):

Consider an inner `concat` on similar data frames then run a final `concat` to bind all together:

```
concatenated = pd.concat([pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1),
                          pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=1)],
                         keys = ['1h', '2h'],
                         names=('Period', 'Data', 'Position'),
                         axis=1)

print(concatenated)  

Period                  1h                                                    \
Data                   Sup                 Inf                 Sup       Inf   
Position                 1         2         1         2         3         3   
2020-01-01 00:00  0.189802  0.675083  0.624484  0.781774  0.453101  0.224525   
2020-01-01 01:00  0.249818  0.829180  0.190488  0.923107  0.495873  0.278201   
2020-01-01 02:00  0.602634  0.494915  0.612672  0.903609  0.426809  0.248981   

Period                  2h                                                    
Data                   Sup                 Inf                 Sup       Inf  
Position                 1         2         1         2         3         3  
2020-01-01 00:00  0.746499  0.385714  0.008561  0.961152  0.988231  0.897454  
2020-01-01 01:00  0.643730  0.365023  0.812249  0.291733  0.045417  0.414968  
2020-01-01 02:00  0.887567  0.680102  0.978388  0.018501  0.695866  0.679730
```

Comment: @Parfait. Thanks but I am actually chasing `pd.concat`, trying to keep as few of them as possible because of performance optimization. I expect `rename()` to be faster than 2 `concat()`, right?   The data I have given only show 4 DataFrames. But I generate them in loops, and there can be hundred of them, with much more data. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Wouah, am I missing something? Your solution is actually 33% faster than the `rename()`. Is it something to be expected? (I worked with these 4 DataFrames, but increased their length over a 4 year period...)

Comment: Glad to help. Not sure why you see timing differences. Solution here can be integrated in loops or even list comprehension that builds lists of data frames for `concat`.